# While running airflow on docker I get : standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "permission denied"

Tags: docker, airflow

I am trying to setup airflow on `ubuntu` with **Docker**. And when I start airflow server I am getting the error

**ERROR:**

> "standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "permission denied" and my container is continuously restarting.

I tried running it as user and also root but its of no use. Also I have added the docker group to user and still no use.

Comment: SElinux checked ? or Mounted Volumes ?

Comment: see this also : https://forums.docker.com/t/solved-msg-standard-init-linux-go-exec-user-process-caused-permission-denied/72664

Comment: I have checked these and yes mounted volumes with exec permission. Can file permission of entrypoint script cause permission issues? But I have tried opening the permissions for entrypoint as well.

Comment: you need to share your setup/file to help us help you :)

Comment: Do you mean the entrypoint script?

ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'processor': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/airflow/logs/scheduler'